# How to define a length for a custom type mapping in DBAL?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, migration, mapping, dbal

I've defined a custom mapping following https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html and it works but I need make:entity to ask for a length for the type in the same way it does for a string. More importantly migrate needs to honour the length value.

The type is 'MyEncrypted' which becomes varbinary in MySQL, make:entity does this fine but I don't want to have to make 'MyEncrypted64', 'MyEncrypted1024', 'MyEncrypted65535' when I feel I should be able to just provide the length. Likewise with doctrine:schema:update --force.

What needs to be done to have length asked for and processed?

I notice that if I have @ORM\Column(type="MyEncrypted", length=37) that the '37' does make it into the $fieldDeclaration var but migrate refuses to acknowledge length changes in the entity PHP file, claming no change when doing 'make:migration'. Likewise with doctrine:schema:update --force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave up in the end and just went with the somewhat unsatisfactory (but functioning) longblob type as Doctrine seems to have no concept of variable-length varbinary types.

In testing longblob seems around 50% longer (0.16mS vs 0.11mS) than varbinary in query execution over 128k records. It's still 'quick enough' but less than desirable vs a pure SQL implementation.